# callback function in c++

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

The code describes two classes that implement callback function, the function must should be member function in the class parameter that passed in template.
Below the code i attached the relevent error message i get.

> a.h

```
template <class CLASSNAME>
class a
{
public:
    typedef void (CLASSNAME::*myFunction)();

    a(CLASSNAME& myObject, myFunction callback) :
    m_myObject(myObject)
    {
        m_myFuntion = callback;
    }

    void update()
    {
        (m_myObject).*(m_myFuntion);
    }

    myFunction m_myFuntion;
    CLASSNAME& m_myObject;
};
```

> dummy.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

class dummy
{
public:
    dummy()
    {
        var = 14;
    }


    void func()
    {
        printf("func!!");
    }

    int var;
};
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "a.h"
#include "dummy.h"


void main()
{
    dummy dum;

    a<dummy> avar(dum, &(dummy::func));

    avar.update();

    system("pause");
}
```

i am trying to implement the callback function and  i get the following error message:

```
C2298 missing call to bound pointer to member function
```

what the problem is?

Comment: this may have already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778498/c-pointer-to-member-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a lot of parentheses, they're just not in the right place. The correct syntax for calling a pointer-to-member function is:

```
void update()
{
    (m_myObject.*m_myFuntion)();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using parentheses in the wrong places:

This:

```
 a<dummy> avar(dum, &(dummy::func));
```

should be this:

```
 a<dummy> avar(dum, &dummy::func);
```

And this:

```
(m_myObject).*(m_myFuntion);
```

should be:

```
(m_myObject.*m_myFuntion)();
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/0jBlgT)