# make a function return a pointer to a function within a class (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11

I found this question here but now I want to extend it. so I have the following class in one file and it works correctly:

```
typedef int (*fptr)();

int f1() {
    return 1;
}

int f2() {
   return 2;
}




fptr f( char c ) {
    if ( c == '1' ) {
        return f1;
    }
    else {
        return f2;
    }
}
```

But when I want to move the functions in another file and make a factory out of them, I get an error that I cannot understand.

it would be like this:

Header:

```
public class Factories{
   public:
     int f1();
     int f2();
}
```

CPPFile:

```
int f1() {
    return 1;
}

int f2() {
   return 2;
}
```

Header:

```
public class FactoryClass{
   public:
     fptr f( char c );
}
```

CPPFile:

```
typedef int (*fptr)();
fptr f( char c ) {
    if ( c == '1' ) {
        return Factories::f1;
    }
    else {
        return Factories::f2;
    }
}
```

Here in the returns of this FactoryClass Function I get the error "return value type does not match the function type".
Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: In C++ you can simply overload a pure virtual function which means you don't need a function pointer.

Comment: typedef int (*fptr)(); is not a pointer to the member function of the Factories class, that would be **typedef int (Factories::*fptr)();**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Factories::f1` is not a normal function, it is a member function.  Since it is a member function it needs to take a pointer to the object that called it so it can affect that instance.  This means the type of a member function includes what type of object it is called from so a pointer to `f1` actually has the type

```
int (Factories::*)()
```

You will either have to make `fptr`

```
typedef int (Factories::*fptr)();
```

or make the functions `static` so they act like regular functions.

Comment: Or keep them in the class but make them `static`.

Comment: @MarvinSielenkemper I said that in my last sentence.

Comment: Ah, sorry! This was meant for a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

the member functions Facotires::f1 you are returning just have the wrong signature. If possible, make them (f1 and f2) static. If not, bind the respective class instance (using boost::bind or std::bind)

Answer (score 1):

The function type changed when you put them in a class. The new type should be `typedef int (Factories::*fptr)();`

[C++: Calling member function via pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778498/c-pointer-to-member-function)