# Passing a member function as arguments using pointer-to-member-function C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member

I am trying to pass a member function as argument using `pointer-to-member-function`. I have already seen some links like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778498/c-pointer-to-member-function) but I could not solve the problem.

The class Foo has two member functions. I need to pass the `addition` function as an argument to the `NewOper` function. 
This is my code. I can correctly use pointer to call the `addition` function but it gives me an error when I try to pass it as an argument to `NewOper` function. I appreciate it if you tell me how I can fix it. (The last two lines cause error)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Foo{
public:
    int addition(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }

    int NewOper(int x, int y, int(*fnc2call)(int, int))
    {
        int r;
        r = (*fnc2call)(x, y);
        return (r);
    }
};
int main()
{
    int m,n, k, l;
    int (Foo::*fptr) (int, int) = &Foo::addition;
    Foo obj;
    m=(obj.*fptr)(1,2);
    Foo* p = &obj;
    n=(p->*fptr)(3,4);
    cout << m << endl;
    cout << n << endl;
    //**********************
    int (Foo::*fptr) (int, int, int(*fnc2call)) = &Foo::NewOper;
    k = (obj.*fptr)(1, 2, addition);
}
```

Comment: This looks quite similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130322/how-do-you-pass-a-member-function-pointer  I'm not quite sure it's a duplicate, though.

Comment: `Foo::addition` need to be `static` to be able to be passed to `NewOper`.

Comment: Which part is your question about? Why have you commented out the last 2 lines?

Comment: @Barmar, My question is about the last two lines. I uncommented them. These two line give me error.

Comment: Remember, member functions have their `this` pointer as a hidden parameter, too, so a normal function point won't work with them.

Answer (score 1):

You already have answer in your own code:

`int (Foo::*fptr) (int, int) = &Foo::addition` - here you correctly declared `fptr` as pointer to function, which is (non static) member of class `Foo`

But you forgot to do the same in you `NewOper` function definition:

`int NewOper(int x, int y, int(*fnc2call)(int, int))` - this function wants address of **free** function as 3rd argument. Redefine it in the same way you declared `fptr`. But then you'll need to pass also pointer to an object of class Foo to this function

Alternatively, you can make your function `addition` function static as Jarod42 suggested (actually, the way it is written now, there is no reason for it to be member of class Foo unless you have further plan on it). Then you'll need to remove `Foo::` from `fptr` definition